# Print the shape by getting sides and angle

Tags: java

Get four length from the user and also get one internal angle.Using that print what shape is that? I tried this.

```
    Scanner in =new Scanner(System.in);
    int l1=in.nextInt();
    int l2=in.nextInt();
    int l3=in.nextInt();
    int l4=in.nextInt();
    int L=l1;
    int angle=in.nextInt();
    if((l1==L)&&(l2==L)&&(l3==L)&&(l4==L))
    {
        if(angle==90)
            System.out.println("SQUARE");
    }
```

I do this for SQUARE check.Now i want to find for IRREGULAR QUADRILATERAL.How can i check for this shape?

Comment: This isn't really an appropriate topic for this site.  This a geometry problem, not a programming problem.  Maybe you should post this in the Mathematics stack exchange site. - But then again, I'm curious...what inputs do you want to have the user enter?  What do you mean "check for"?  If you are talking about the same inputs, do you care which set of sides lengths the entered angle is between?  Are you just asking if those inputs could produce a valid QL?  Your question is pretty vague.

Comment: This question belongs to math.stackexchange.com.